# Prevent Fall Damage

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2, what kinds of things can you land on to soften fall damage?

**Edit:** I'm looking specifically for things to land on. My perks are already set to a configuration that I'm happy with, so I don't want to change them - I just want to know what to keep my eye out for when jumping from high places

Comment: I removed the xbox tag because MW2 is essentially the same across platforms.

Comment: See Mechkos answer

Comment: that's one thing. are there more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing to do is land on a **mattress**.  For example, there are mattresses at the bottom of the sniper ledge on Afghan, and it always amazes me the number of people who miss them.  If you are very careful, you can often 'slide' down things, but that is touch and go.

EDIT: Oh yeah... and commando pro.  I totally forgot that one.

Comment: The other two mentioned Commando Pro first, for the record

Comment: I know, but I was looking for an answer without Commando Pro. This is the only answer that includes mention of objects to land on.

Comment: You can also jump to the tail of the plane from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can slot the Commando Pro perk to have no fall damage at all.

Answer (score 2):

Another more general method to negate fall damage is with the [Commando Perk](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Commando_Pro).

When you upgrade this to Commando Pro, and equip it, it completely negates fall damage.

You can unlock it by getting 20 melee kills with the original Commando perk equipped (via knife, tactical knife or riot shield)

Comment: omg... I can't believe I forgot that...

Answer (score 2):

Landing on anything after you take even light bullet damage will most likely kill you from a height of 15 feet unless you are using Commando Pro. I know you like your perks the way you have them but being adaptive is 100% essential to dominating in this game.

In response to MMO-Tragic -- there is also an achievement for falling 30 feet and dying, though no achievement for falling 30 feet and living...

Answer (score 1):

I found that stair cases on sides of buildings let you hope down quite fast if you bounce of stair case.

Dont forget there is an achievement for surviving a 15 foot fall !

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying out different things, and I've found that car hoods and garbage dumpsters work well.

I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Car hoods are dangerous.  You could find yourself dead from an exploding car doing this too much.